# How to fix the size of UIBarButtonItem when its font weight changes

Tags: swift, size, uibarbuttonitem

Below is a short piece of demo code distilled from my project. It consists of a UINavigationBar, UINavigationItem, and several UIBarButtonItems. Tapping on a barButtonItem highlights it and dims the others. In doing so, it is understandable that the font size changes, but I want the size of the barButtonItems themselves to be fixed. That way, when I tap randomly on the barButtonItems, they don't appear to jiggle as their title text shrinks and expands. How do I make the barButtonItems resist resizing as their title text changes?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var barButtonItems: [UIBarButtonItem]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 40))
        navBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(navBar)
        
        let navItem = UINavigationItem()
        let appleBarBtnItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Apple", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barItemTapped))
        let bananaBarBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Banana", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barItemTapped))
        let kiwiBarBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Kiwi", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barItemTapped))
        let pearBarBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Pear", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barItemTapped))
        let orangeBarBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Orange", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barItemTapped))
        barButtonItems = [appleBarBtnItem, bananaBarBtnItem, kiwiBarBtnItem, pearBarBtnItem, orangeBarBtnItem]

        navItem.leftBarButtonItems = barButtonItems
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
        
        setCurrentBarItem(appleBarBtnItem)
    }
    
    func setCurrentBarItem(_ barBtnItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        for btn in barButtonItems {
            highlight(btn, turnedOn: (btn == barBtnItem) )
        }
    }
    
    func highlight(_ button: UIBarButtonItem, turnedOn: Bool) {
        button.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7230747342, green: 0.9554787278, blue: 0.9893732667, alpha: 1)
        let weight: UIFont.Weight = turnedOn ? .bold : .thin
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [ .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: weight)]
        button.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    }
    
    @objc func barItemTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        setCurrentBarItem(sender)
    }
}
```

[image: barButtonItems change size as their titles change size]

Answer (score 0):

One reason they are jiggling is that you are setting `setTitleTextAttributes` only for `.normal` state. Add it for `.selected` as well so it jiggle less however it won't fully fix your issue.
Sth like this

```
button.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .selected)
```

I would suggest to try to add some margin to the ui text holder element of the UIBarButtonItems. May fix it!

Comment: No, that didn't help. Looks like I have to give up on having a ```.bold``` font weight for the selected barButtonItem and a ```.thin``` font weight when it's not, because the change in font weight expands or shrinks the width of the barButtonItem. I finally decided on simply changing the colors of the barButtonItems and providing a simple animation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to give up on having a `.bold` font weight for the selected barButtonItem and a `.thin` font weight when it's not, because the change in font weight expands or shrinks the width of the barButtonItem causing the juxtaposing barButtonItems to shift and jiggle around when I tap on them. I finally decided on only changing the colors of the barButtonItems and providing a simple animation:

```
    func highlight(_ button: UIBarButtonItem, turnedOn: Bool) {
        let tintColor = turnedOn ? 
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.7230747342, green: 0.9554787278, blue: 0.9893732667, alpha: 1) 
            : 
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.1901655495, green: 0.5488880277, blue: 0.7976593971, alpha: 1)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, 
                       delay: 0, 
                       options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseInOut], 
                       animations: { button.tintColor = tintColor }, 
                       completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: barButtonItem selection visually improved]